# cassandra 3.0.9 internode_encryption with IBM JDK 1.8?

Tags: cassandra, ibm-jdk

In addition to changing keystore and truststore passwords and installing corresponding files in conf, I made the following changes to cassandra.yaml:

```
internode_encryption: all
algorithm: IbmX509
```

In addition I set the following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=/share/ibm-jdk1.8
JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true
```

I invoke bin/cassandra and eventually see...

> ```
> ***
> SSLContextImpl:  Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.ay
> SSLContextImpl:  Using X509TrustManager com.ibm.jsse2.aC
> JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom SHA2DRBG from provider IBMJCE version 1.8
> trigger seeding of SecureRandom
> done seeding SecureRandom
> JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom SHA2DRBG from provider IBMJCE version 1.8
> JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA1withECDSA from provider TBD via init 
> JsseJCE:  Using signature NONEwithECDSA from provider TBD via init 
> JsseJCE:  Using KeyAgreement ECDH from provider IBMJCE version 1.8
> JsseJCE:  Using KeyFactory EC from provider IBMJCE version 1.8
> JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator EC from provider TBD via init 
> JsseJCE:  Using cipher AES/GCM/NoPadding from provider TBD via init 
> CipherBox:  Using cipher AES/GCM/NoPadding from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
> JsseJCE:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD via init 
> CipherBox:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider from init IBMJCE version 1.8
> jdk.tls.client.protocols is defined as null
> SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled
> SSLv3 protocol was requested but was not enabled
> SUPPORTED: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
> SERVER_DEFAULT: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
> CLIENT_DEFAULT: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
> WARN  10:55:39 Filtering out [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> ```
>
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] as it isn't supported by the
>   socket
>       Exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) encountered during startup: SSLv2Hello is not a recognized protocol.
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSLv2Hello is not a recognized protocol.

Please advise.

Comment: My advice would be to *not* use the IBM JDK.  I'm sure it can work, but I don't know of too many (any) who use it successfully with Cassandra.

Comment: The question is why does it not work.  Is it the fault of Cassandra, IBM JDK, or user error?